# What were "atoms" in Bitcoin-0.1.0?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

Satoshi's first implementation of Bitcoin had a kind of internal marketplace as well. [In that part of the code, `Atoms` are "added" and "propagated"](https://github.com/Dan-McG/bitcoin-0.1.0/blob/master/src/market.cpp#L143) but I'm having a hard time understanding what these data were in modern Bitcoin terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believed to be part of a rating system that was never implemented.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5381576.0